# how to find the last level child nodes in tree kind structure in database using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a parent child relationship stored in a table

If I query with 1, I want to retrieve all the LAST LEVEL Children of 1.
I should get back 5, 6,8.

Ignore any cyclical data that comes along.

Please see the attached image [image]

Comment: please tag the database being used.

Comment: Cycles are not "accidental", they are put there by whoever is inserting the data.  In addition, they make the question meaningless.

Comment: @Gordon you are right. I will remove the cyclical comment. Since it was third party provided data, i was thinking of exception scenarios.

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a hierarchical query and restrict the output to only the non-cyclic leaf rows using the [pseudocolumns](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns001.htm) `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` and `CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( parent_column, child_column ) AS
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 8 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT child_column
FROM   your_table
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF  = 1
AND    CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE = 0
START WITH parent_column = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR child_column = parent_column
```

**Output**:

```
CHILD_COLUMN
------------
           5
           6
           8
```

Comment: This may well be the right answer but does not help with understanding what is going on. For example which part of the query causes it to only output the last level children ?

Comment: @BriteSponge The last children of a tree structure are its [leaves](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TreeLeaf.html). The pseudocolumns `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1` will restrict it to only outputting the leaves and `CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE = 0` will restrict it to non-cyclic rows (which was part of the original question before it was edited out).

Comment: Thanks MT0. Works fine. Will add back the edit part so that its helpful for others

Comment: @MT0 - That's fine. I've used hierarchical queries and know how they work. I didn't see any point adding, essentially, the same query as yours but thought some explanation would be useful for people looking for an answer later.